# fetching flickr/picasa pictures using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr, picasa

I want to add a slide show of pictures from one my photo albums from flick/picasa.Is it possible to fetch the images javascriptically on the page and then show them using jQuery(that i can do :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flickrshow](http://www.flickrshow.com/install/) is what you want then. it uses very simple integration, and only JavaScript. Jquery-Flickr also does that in a very nice way.

Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-flickr/)

There isn't much support for Picasa yet, but you can always extend the existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/EmbedPicasaGallery) for Picasa.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a developer, then I'd suggest you use this [little jQuery snippet](http://code.lancepollard.com/picasa-jquery-plugin) to load any image / album data from picasa you want, and then use one of the many [slideshow](http://slidesjs.com) / image viewer plugins you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Image Gallery is an extension to blueimp Gallery, a touch-enabled, responsive and customizable image & video gallery.
It displays images and videos in the modal dialog of the Bootstrap framework, features swipe, mouse and keyboard navigation, transition effects, fullscreen support and on-demand content loading and can be extended to display additional content types.

[script Link](http://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/)

Demo : [My album](http://premjith.in/gallery)